# How to add space on both sides of a character of a string in java?

Tags: java, string

How can I add space on both sides of a character of a string in java?

Ex- suppose string is "`s_id=5 and s_name!=6`" and if I want to add space on both the sides of `=` then output string will be like "`s_id = 5 and s_name!=6`"

I am trying this using replace and contains method...

I check `if(str.contains("="))` then replace it with(`" = "`) but it also adds space for `!=`.

Comment: You need to decide then after/before what characters the space should be added. You should specify what other characters should be ignored before `=`, for example, decide if `>=` or `<=` should be ignored.

Comment: Please update your question, as your question misleads the reader to believe you really want a string replacement, while its a rules based replacement. Being specific will help with more concrete answers

Comment: Additionally, please provide the complete criteria for the adding the space before and after "=". From your example, your rule seems arbitrary, could you please be more specific?

Comment: Objective is to add space on both the sides of each operator in string (=,!=).
When I check that if character is =, I will add space but space is added for != also. because it also contains = 

that's the problem which i want to solve that I want to add spaces for a character which is STRICTLY the same character...hope now its more specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<![><!+-])[=]", " = ");
```

Put the characters you don't want preceeding `=` between square brackets in the regexp. The expression in the answer ignores `+=`, `-+`, `<=`, `<=`, and `!=`.

Comment: thanks...its worked for my problem..But as I dont know much about regular expressions. Can you give regex to distinguish between >= and > means if I want to add space on both the sides of >= then it should not add in case of > Thanks in adv.

Comment: @Sam When you want to add spaces around *longer* strings and ignore *shorter* ones, you can avoid regular expressions altogether: you can call `s.replaceAll(">=", " >= ")`, and it will ignore `>` and `=` when they are *not* next to each other.

Comment: Learning regular expressions is a good thing, just start with it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight here you have given example of ignoring +,<,> and ! etc..now what to write if I also want to ignore " before = ?

Comment: @Sam You can put double quotes into the list. Of course you will need to *escape* it with a backslash, like this `"[\"><!+-]"`; otherwise, Java would report a compile error. Note that if a dash `-` is present, it needs to be the first or the last character on the list, because it has special meaning inside square brackets if it has other characters on both sides.

Comment: @Sam: Try this book http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/0596528124/ref=as_li_ss_tl?tag=vitavonni-21 or any other book with "regular expressions" in the title and good reviews.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think your solution put extra space where there are space before and after the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = value.replaceAll("([$_\\d\\w])([^$_\\d\\w]+)", "$1 $2")
             .replaceAll("([^$_\\d\\w]+)([$_\\d\\w])", "$1 $2")
             .replaceAll("\\s+", " "))
```

This code will add separators to any operator, and remove unecessary spaces.

`s_id=5 and s_name!=6` will become `s_id = 5 and s_name != 6`

Considering that variables can be composed of **$** _ **digits** or **letters**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceAll()` method in the `String` class to help achieve this

example:

```
final String spacedEquals = " = ";
String s = "s_id=5 and s_name!=6";

//this will add a space on either side of the '='
s.replaceAll("=", spacedEquals);
```

hope this helps

Comment: No its not working..

Output of your code will be like: s_id = 5 and s_name! = 6
i.e. it adds space for != also...

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
    private String replace( String str, String pattern, String replace ) 
{
    int s = 0;
    int e = 0;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while ( (e = str.indexOf( pattern, s ) ) >= 0 ) 
    {
        result.append(str.substring( s, e ) );
        result.append( replace );
        s = e+pattern.length();
    }
    result.append( str.substring( s ) );
    return result.toString();
}
```