# Using Java Regex, how to add a space before and after a parenthesis?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I tried many variants of different solutions explained here

[How to add space on both sides of a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767555/how-to-add-space-on-both-the-sides-of-a-character-of-a-string-in-java)

[Regex add space between all punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954125/regex-add-space-between-all-punctuation)

[Add space after capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886091/insert-space-after-capital-letter)

As well as other ones regarding parenthesis (and many more)

[Regex to match parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205344/regular-expression-to-match-parentheses-and-brackets-for-javascript)

I have a String and I simply want this : hi()

To become this : hi ( )

What I have tried so far :

```
if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
            phrase.replaceAll("\\(", " \\( ");
        }
```

The if works fine but the replaceAll doesn't do anything.

I read online that I might need to put the previous values in the replaceAll so I tried the following

```
if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
    phrase.replaceAll("(.*)\\(", " \\( ");
}
```

As well as this

```
    if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
    phrase.replaceAll("(.*)\\(", "(.*) \\( ");
}
```

And this

```
if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
        phrase.replaceAll("(.*)\\((.*)", "(.*) \\( (.*)");
    }
```

At this point I feel that I am just trying random stuff and I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: [See this](https://regex101.com/r/TSv6V1/2). Regex: `\(`; Replace ` ( `

Comment: Single backslash doesn't work in Java. The equivalent is \\ or  \' or \" and I tried them all

Comment: From the link above, if you go to the code generator section and select java, you'll get this page: https://regex101.com/r/TSv6V1/2/codegen?language=java. What I posted above in the comment is the pure regex. You need to escape the characters in Java thereafter (as the link in this comment shows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replaceAll doesn't mutate the string. Try

```
if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
    System.out.println(phrase.replaceAll("\\(", " \\( "));
    // => f ( )
}
```

or

```
if (phrase.matches("^.*[(].*$")){
    phrase = phrase.replaceAll("\\(", " \\( "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, Strings are immutable. So you might want to assign the replaceAll result to a variable.

`phrase = phrase.replaceAll("\\(", " (");`

Also your if condition can be omitted, cause the `replaceAll` will replace the strings, only if it finds a match.